# Create Many to Many Polymorphic Relationship using custom table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many, polymorphic-relationship

How can I create a Many to Many relationships using the custom polymorphic table?

**model_has_tags**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('tag_id';
$table->string('model_type');
$table->integer('model_id');
```

**tags**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
```

**user**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('full_name');
```

I try this but not working.

***Tag Model***

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(User::class, 'model');
    }
```

***User Model***

```
public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'model');
    }
```

error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'stormport.models' doesn't exist (SQL: select `tags`.*, `models`.`model_id` as `pivot_model_id`, `models`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id`....
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

**User Model**

```
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'model', 'model_has_tags');
    }
```