# customize table name polymorphic many-to-many relationship in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, polymorphic-relationship

Trying to implement a [polymorphic many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations), similar to the one in the documentation.

In my case, for `label` instead of `tag`. And using different table names

```
apples / oranges / ...
  id - integer
  name - string

label_types
  id - integer
  name - string

labels
  label_type_id - integer -- foreign ID for LabelType
  labeling_type - string
  labeling_id - integer - ID of the model this labelType is used for


// Apple / Orange / ...

    public function labels(LabelType $type = null)
    {
        // need to provide table name, as expected default table name is labelings
        return $this->morphToMany(Label::class, 'labeling', 'labels');
    }

// Label

    public function apples()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Apple::class, 'labeling', 'labels');
    }

    public function oranges()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Orange::class, 'labeling', 'labels');
    }
```

This results in an error.

```
$apple->labels;

Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'labels' 

select
  `labels`.*,
  `labels`.`label_id` as `pivot_label_id`,
  `labels`.`label_type` as `pivot_label_type`
from
  `labels`
  inner join `labels` on `labels`.`id` = `labels`.`label_id`
where
  `labels`.`label_id` = 1
  and `labels`.`label_type` = 'App\Models\Apple'
```

In the example above I have [added the table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59082278/create-many-to-many-polymorphic-relationship-using-custom-table) to `morphToMany()`.
Same error when using `labelings` as table name and adding to Label model: `protected $table = 'labelings';`

How do I get this to work? I do want to use `label_types` as it better fits with the rest of my application.
I looked at other polymorphic questions on Stackoverflow, but could not find an answer.

Comment: I really do not understand why you want other table names. If you use the Laravel naming conventions, everything works out of the box. Using other table names only makes it harder to code. And above all, difficult to maintain.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The documentation uses 'tag' as an example, but it should work in other environments as well right? Laravel does not provide 'tag' functionality, it provides 'many-to-many polymorphic relationship' functionality. My example is pretty similar to the "added the table name" link.